# Positive definite proposition contradiction

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra

Consider the proposition: If $A$ is a positive definite $n \times n$ matrix, then there is a positive number $c$ such that $Q(\mathbf{u}) = \langle A\mathbf{u},\mathbf{u}
\rangle \geq  c\lVert \mathbf{u}\rVert^2$ for all $\mathbf{u}$

Now consider the function $Q(\mathbf{u}) = x^4$, but there is no $c\gt 0$ such that $Q(\mathbf{u}) \geq cx^2$ for all $x \neq 0$.

Why doesn't this contradict the proposition?

Comment: You cannot choose Q as you wish, it must be what you have written...

Comment: That's not correct. I'm not choosing Q as I wish, setting Q to x^4 it's just a statement to say that there is a matrix A that's positive definite since Q = the definition of positive definite.

Comment: mmmm you're right, my fault

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing things. The expression $\langle Au,u\rangle$ is obtained from a vector $u$ and a matrix $A$, and it is a fixed number that depends on $A$ and $u$.

To "contradict the proposition" you would need to have a positive-definite matrix $A$ such that no $c$ exists with $\langle Au,u\rangle\geq c\,\langle u,u\rangle$. This is equivalent to the existence of a sequence of unit vectors such that $\langle Au_n,u_n\rangle\to0$.

When you say $Q(u)=x^4$, is it hard to see what you mean. You want $\langle Au,u\rangle=x^4$. What do you mean by that? How is $x$ related to $u$? What's your matrix that contradicts the proposition?

In your "contradiction", you seem to be wanting to say that $\|u\|=x$, because you write $cx^2$ to mimic the proposition. In what sense is $\langle Au,u\rangle=x^4$? What is $A$? What is $u$?